# How to get an iframe to occupy full width (i.e. display like a div)

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get an `iframe` to behave like a normal non-floating `DIV` does. i.e. occupy full width of parent. Is this possible? Looking for something equivalent to saying `display: div;`

**Edit**: I'm not looking for `width: 100%` since i have another floating element to the left. A non-floating DIV would take the rest of the space on the right. This is the behavior i'm looking to achieve.

**Working**: With a `DIV` on the right - http://jsbin.com/onaxax/1/edit

**Not Working**: With an `IFRAME` on the right - http://jsbin.com/erapuv/1/edit

Comment: have you tried setting the style="width:100%" ?

Comment: @PabloRomeo - Please see my edit above. i'll post a fiddle to demo what i'm looking for.

Comment: Got it, the edit was helpful in clarifying. Check out Litek's answer. That might do the trick.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have to wrap your iframe in element with `overflow:hidden` that would occupy the remaining space, and than set the iframe's width to 100%.

[Example](http://codepen.io/thelitek/pen/IuEhc).

Comment: It's called display:block

Comment: would be awesome if you were fixing the height typo in the css :). Thanks

Comment: With HTML5 this no longer works: IFRAME width attribute must be pixels, and cannot be percentage.

Comment: Is it w3c validate if I add 100% instead of a numeric value?