# Responsive video element not working on mobile

Tags: css, iframe, mobile, web

OK, so I am trying to get an embedded YouTube video to play nice on my site. It is working fine on desktop and re-sizes when I change viewport size, but on mobile (iPhone 4 and 6 and an HTC running Android) the video is not resizing properly.

The iframe is wrapped in a div and the code is as follows:

`<div class="videocontainer"><iframe.......></iframe></div>`

```
.videoWrapper {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 */
    padding-top: 30px;
    height: 0;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.videocontainer iframe, .video-container object, .video-container embed {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

I have also tried media queries with no luck, using this to test:

```
@media only screen 
    and (min-device-width: 320px) 
    and (max-device-width: 480px)
    and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
    and (orientation: portrait) {.videorecipe {width: 10%;} 
}
```

I realize the 10% is to small, I added it simply to test.

You can see the page here:
http://lowfodmapdiet.tv/recipe/chicken-and-vegetables-gluten-free-pie

Comment: Looks duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13158883/how-to-get-an-iframe-to-occupy-full-width-i-e-display-like-a-div